# Supposed projection matrix isn't projection in eigendecomposition

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection, projection-matrices

I was trying to evaluate the eigendecomposition of the matrix $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}0&b\\-b&0\end{matrix}\right)$$I easily found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to be

$$
\lambda_1 = ib \longrightarrow v_{\lambda_1} = \left(\begin{matrix}1\\i\end{matrix}\right) \\[20pt]
\lambda_2 = -ib \longrightarrow v_{\lambda_2} = \left(\begin{matrix}1\\-i\end{matrix}\right)
$$

And from this is just a matter of evaluating the projection matrices on $v_1,v_2$ because for eigendecomposition we have that

$$
A = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_i\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_i}\tag 1
$$

The projection matrix can be found easily as

$$
\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T
$$

so in my case

$$
\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_1} = \left(\begin{matrix}1\\i\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&i\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1&i\\i&-1\end{matrix}\right) \\ \hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_1} = \left(\begin{matrix}1\\-i\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&-i\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1&-i\\-i&1\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then I tried, just for double-checking, that this were indeed projection matrices. I used the definition

$$
\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathbf v}^2 = \hat{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathbf v}
$$

but this **is not clearly the case**. As you can see, for $\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_1}$ we have

$$
\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_1}^2 = \left(\begin{matrix}1&i\\i&-1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&i\\i&-1\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Clearly a projection shouldn't be nilpotent! And not even only that! Formula $(1)$ doesn't hold, neither do

$$
\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_i}\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_j} = \delta_{ij}\hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_j}\\
\sum_{j=1}^n \hat{\mathcal{P}}_{v_j} = \mathbb{I}
$$

> **Question**: where is the problem in this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it in $\Bbb C$, you have to use the conjugate transponse $v^H$, not $v^T$ (and be careful that you may need to normalize the vectors).

Comment: With $v^H$ you mean the *conjugate transpose*?

Comment: @DavideMorgante Yes.

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Ahah thanks